# Deploying Spring on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy my Spring Application in Java to AWS Elastic Bean stalk. But I have a few problems caused by not understand AWS enough and tutorials which are to old (Interface changed etc.)

Few questions:

I created a Application and it is configured as Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running. 
[image]

so far so good. 
When I click on the Configuration menu entry, I wanted to enable a mysql instance / db, but I am not able to modify it (select an instance class etc.) or get access to the database with e.g SequelPro. 
[image]

In "Software" where I can set the environment variables I tried to get a connection to the database, if it worked I don't know because I can not find the log for the spring application deployed and cannot access the database from outside. 
Connection String looks like this. ("someurl" is the real url ^^):

```
jdbc:mysql://someurl.com/ebdb
```

[image]

Btw. when I click on the URL of the environment I get an 404.

I hope someone can help me deploying.

Answer (score 1):

> When I click on the Configuration menu entry, I wanted to enable a mysql instance / db, but I am not able to modify it (select an instance class etc.) or get access to the database with e.g SequelPro.

Beanstalk is container-based service, you can't run MySQL on same instance, you should start corresponding one from RDS or use a separate EC2 instance. Beanstalk instances should be stateless as any moment new instance can be added or removed.

> I can not find the log for the spring application deployed

You can access logs and access the instance via EB CLI  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html
Tou should be able to test DB connectivity same way

Comment: is there any good tutorial which is not outdated how to deploy a spring application with database?

Comment: If you want to run Benastalk there are several good tutorials on Amazon. If you want to deploy it on EC2 instance it is same as deplying an application to any linux via SSH. If you want to learn in depth I recommend acloud.guru

Comment: Thank you. acloud.guru sounds interesting